# regex for matching latitude, longitudes without any character

Tags: regex

I am looking for one regex which strictly allows 2 floating point numbers which are comma separated.

Test cases:

```
0,0
0.021312311323,0
0,0.012312312312
1.1,0.9836373
```

Regex that I have tried is

```
^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$\D+|\d*\.?\d+
```

These are latitudes and longitudes but I just want 2 values in these paremeters.

This regex fails in:

```
-10a, 10a
10a,10b
```

I would really appreciate any help and guidance.

Comment: I think the patterns at the end are redundant, try just `^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(?:\.\d+)?|90(?:\.0+)?), *[-+]?(180(?:\.0+)?|(?:1[0-7]\d|[1-9]?\d)(?:\.\d+)?)$`, see https://regex101.com/r/YaTCfB/1

Comment: Please post this as answer it is working for me I tried too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex ends with a couple of redundant patterns, you should remove `\D+|\d*\.?\d+` after `$`. As `$` means the end of string, there can be no more text after it, and the `\D+|\d*\.?\d+` requires one or more non-digit chars, or just matches any float or integer number with `\d*\.?\d+` - this matched your unwelcome strings.

You can use

```
^([-+]?(?:[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d+)?|90(?:\.0+)?)),\s*([-+]?(?:180(?:\.0+)?|(?:1[0-7]\d|[1-9]?\d)(?:\.\d+)?))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YaTCfB/2). Note I converted some capturing groups into non-capturing, so that there remain just two "notional" capturing groups in the pattern.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([-+]?(?:[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d+)?|90(?:\.0+)?))` - Group 1:

  - `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
  - `(?:[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d+)?|90(?:\.0+)?)` - either a number from 0 to 89 (`[1-8]?\d`) and then an optional fractional part (`(?:\.\d+)?`) or `90` and then an optional `.` followed with one or more `0` chars
- `,\s*` - a comma and 0+ whitespace chars
- `([-+]?(?:180(?:\.0+)?|(?:1[0-7]\d|[1-9]?\d)(?:\.\d+)?))` - Group 2:

  - `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
  - `(?:180(?:\.0+)?|(?:1[0-7]\d|[1-9]?\d)(?:\.\d+)?)` - either a `180` number followed with an optional `.` + one or more `0` chars, or a number from 0 to 179 and then an optional fractional part
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is almost correct. You should have stopped at `$` indicating the end of the string.

```js
const testCases = [ "0,0",
                    "0.021312311323,0",
                    "0,0.012312312312",
                    "1.1,0.9836373",
                    "-10a, 10a",
                    "10a,10b"];

const re = /^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/g;


testCases.forEach(tc => {
  if(tc.match(re)) {
    console.log("    VALID : " + tc );
  } else {
    console.log("NOT VALID : " + tc);
  }
});
```